# Pandas memory error with 3.8MB dataset downloaded from sql database

Tags: python, pandas, impala

I've been hit with a very weird error.

When I download datasets from the DWH, using the following code regardless of the query:

```
from impala.dbapi import connect as impala_connect

def read_from_dwh(query):
    '''
    Connect to the DWH, read query and close connection
    '''
    credent = get_credentials_string('DWH', 'user', 'password')
    user = credent[0]
    pasw = credent[1]

    connection = impala_connect(
        host='cloudera-impala-proxy.live.bi.io',
        port=21050,
        user=user,
        password=pasw,
        auth_mechanism='PLAIN',
        use_ssl=True
    )

    df = pd.read_sql(con=connection, sql=query)
    connection.close()

    return df

query = f"SELECT * FROM customer_id"

read_from_dwh(query)
```

This returns a `MemoryError`.

```
empty_df = read_from_dwh(empty_forecast_query)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pavlos\Desktop\WORK\Projects\git\project\venv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-a366e7a5deef>", line 1, in <module>
    empty_df = read_from_dwh(empty_forecast_query)
  File "C:\Users\Pavlos\Desktop\WORK\Projects\git\project\scripts\connections.py", line 67, in read_from_dwh
    df = pd.read_sql(con=connection, sql=query)
MemoryError
```

But when the query is `query = f"SELECT * FROM customer_id LIMIT 10"`, it runs just fine.

I downloaded the file from the DWH manually and read it to memory using `read_csv` from `pandas` and it loads just fine (3.8MB). The function returning the error is `read_sql`.

Any ideas for this behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried `read_sql(..., chunksize=...)`?

Comment: @AKX yes, and it resulted in the same error. I have tried reading line-by-line as well, and didn't work

Comment: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13168 seems relevant... But if you do have the workaround of being able to read the table into a CSV file (programmatically?) and load it into Pandas from there, wouldn't that work for you?

Comment: @akx because that would require me to manually download the needed datasets every time and store them in memory. My issue here is the manual download.

Comment: But you already have code to get an SQLAlchemy connection to your datastore. It's not a big leap to do the query and write into a CSV from there?